# limit to 1 the select2 suggestions if exist 2 or more equal results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, coffeescript, jquery-select2

I have this json on /api/searches file:

```
[{"id":"513dbb61a61654a845000005","text":"ingeniero agrónomo"},{"id":"513a11d4a6165411b2000008","text":"ingeniero agrónomo"}]
```

I'm using select2 to show results.

This is my select2 setting:

```
$('#query_txt').select2
    width: 'resolve'
    minimumInputLength: 3
    tags: false
    showSearchBox: true
    maximumSelectionSize: 1
    closeOnSelect: true
    multiple: false
    ajax:
      url: "/api/searches"
      quietMillis: 100
      dataType: 'json'
      data: (term, page) -> {q: term}
      results: (data, page) ->
        results: data
```

If I type in my input the word `ingeniero agrónomo` select2 suggests the two results, you can see in the next image:

[image]

I want, If exist `2` or more results equal in json, limit to `1` the **select2 suggestions**

**How can I limit to 1 the select2 suggestions if exist 2 or more equal results?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would need to do is to update the results function to process the outputted array from the data function and remove duplicate texts, untested code, but something like this should do it:

```
$('#query_txt').select2
    width: 'resolve'
    minimumInputLength: 3
    tags: false
    showSearchBox: true
    maximumSelectionSize: 1
    closeOnSelect: true
    multiple: false
    ajax:
      url: "/api/searches"
      quietMillis: 100
      dataType: 'json'
      data: (term, page) -> {q: term}
      results: (data, page) ->
        indexes = []
        uniques = []
        i = 0
        while i < data.length
          if indexes[data[i].text] is `undefined`
            indexes[data[i].text] = "defined"
            uniques.push
              id: data[i].text
              text: data[i].text
          i++
        results: uniques
```

Comment: I have edited your answer to coffeescript and fixed the syntax error. Sorry but this solution is not working, I don't get suggestions with this solution.

Comment: Yeah, maybe this time, select2 might need to have an id and text in the output object.

Comment: Thank you but this approach does not work... I don't get suggestions :(.

Comment: I have tested this solution, you will need to translate it to coffescript again, sorry haven't used it, but this should be ok. My test in jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/BgUzc/

Comment: Thank you, Now is working fine :). I have edited your question to coffescript. Thank you!